# Python проверка условий

Tags: python, if, for

Вопрос у меня : есть два списка имен. Как перебрать список имён при условии, что если имя в одном списке использовалось, то выводит сообщение, что надо выбрать другое имя ( например при регистрации на сайте). Если имя не использовалось, то вывести сообщение о его доступности для использования. При этом сравнение должно выполняться без учёта регистра символов. Например если 'СТАС' уже есть есть , то 'стас' уже нельзя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать метод `lower()` приводящий текст в нижний регистр. Для проверки без учёта регистра, лучше приводить к нижнему регистру и искомое слово и список. Вот банальный пример:

```
name = input()
my_list = ["Миша", "петр", "Олег"]

if name.lower() in [item.lower() for item in my_list]:
    print("Имя уже есть в списке.")
else:
    print("Имени нет в списке.")
```

`if name.lower() in [item.lower() for item in my_list]:` есть однострочный вариант записи:

```
for item in my_list:
    if name.lower() in item.lower():
         ...
    else:
         ...
```